# How do I search Bitbucket for files that contain a string and are contained in specific repos?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to search Bitbucket for files that contain the string "MyStr", but only search repos whose name contains "cookbook". Is this possible?

I could not see how to do this with quick file search: https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/02/07/introducing-quick-file-search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a total solution but it is for my use case

You can constrain BB searches to a BB project

So I put the repos I wanted to search into a project (really needed to properly categorize them anyway) and searched the project

Comment: Like this? `project:project1 repo:cookbook_1 repo:cookbook_2 repo:cookbook_3 MyStr`

Answer (score 8):

You can click on the magnifying glass on the left bar (top bar in the new layout) and directly type in the code. It'll allow for searching in the current repository or all your repositories.

Comment: that's only to search file names. The question is about searching "files that contain a string"

Comment: You can search both files as well as code: https://bitbucket.org/blog/introducing-code-aware-search-for-bitbucket-cloud. An example would be https://bitbucket.org/search?q=repo%3Aelasticsearch%20QueryBuilders&account=%7B6f461d1e-a3dd-433b-a0e3-7a69daf6ea47%7D&_ga=2.102217345.1298418300.1521714585-808178982.1506302185

Comment: After the most recent layout change the code search over all accessible repositories is accessible via the search bot on the top right of the page.

Comment: Great question. This is either aggravatingly tedious to figure out and use or, our cloud instance is not set up correctly; we just migrated. None of the answers here work for me. Similarly, nothing I find documented works. Typically we're getting "_No repositories match_" "_We couldn't find what you're looking for in_" or, just "_Something went wrong_." Checking with our administrator.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no such feature yet.

Comment: bitbucket sucks

Comment: 7+ years later and we still can't search for an exact string containing slashes... Who in their right mind thought a "code search" that basically only supports alphanumeric characters was a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

There's a feature in Bitbucket named "Advanced Search". The way I found it was by using the search bar in the top right corner and typing some random text that returns no results and clicking in the Advanced Search link.
Alternatively, you can access the address https://bitbucket.org/search while logged in your account.

You can read the Bitbucket search engine documentation in this link:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/code-search-in-bitbucket-873876782.html

Comment: omg,  Github just allows search everywhere and it works without any special requirements

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question as of today:
in Search bar enter:

"MyStr" repo:cookbook project:yourproject

This will search for "MyStr" in repos, which have in their name word cookbook.
Answer taken from: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-search-syntax-814204781.html

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better

Answer (score 0):

You can use "path" search modifier: `path:directory-or-filename StringToSearchFor`

Documentation [is here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/search-in-bitbucket-cloud) -  works for Bitbucket Server too

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Bitbucket cloud specific answer; we just migrated. My advise is ***don't search Bitbucket for files that contain a string*** unless you have very simple use-cases.

- **Found this:** [Cloud search considerations](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/search-in-bitbucket-cloud/#Code-search-considerations): **Read it VERY carefully**. It is *crazy* finicky and may not find the code that you know exists. I've stopped trying use Bitbucket's code search. Instead, as long as I know the repo. and branch, I clone the repository, checkout the branch, and the search the code myself (Visual Studio, grep, find, or the like).

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** It searches only the master branch of all repos .so you might not get your search item ,if it is saved in other branches.

1.go to dashboard. click on search icon from sidebar

2.click on "search for code"

3.search your string like "Hello World" with double quotes  (works well for more than one word).

reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/code-search-in-bitbucket-873876782.html

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: is there a way to search across all branches?

Comment: This is outdated. the UI has changed.